# How is the ball "activated" in DropShot?

Tags: rocket-league

What determines when the ball loses its shell or goes super-saiyan?

I've heard people claim it has to do with:

- How hard you hit the ball
- How many times the ball has been hit since it touched the floor last
- How high off the floor the ball is

Based on my observations so far, every one of these is incorrect.  So what actually causes it?

Comment: IMO it's based on the amount of times the ball has been juggled without hitting the floor. I have only seen the ball activate directly after being hit by a player. I've never seen it activate mid air which rules out it being based on it's time in the air.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Rocket League's Website](https://www.rocketleague.com/news/dropshot-new-game-mode-march-22/):

> The new ball has three different phases, each more powerful than the last, that determine how much damage is done when the ball smashes into the floor panels. **The second and third phases are activated by multiple Battle-Car hits, so the longer the ball stays off the ground, the more powerful it becomes**. While the first phase of the new ball only damages one tile upon impact, the second and third phases can damage up to seven and 19 panels, respectively.

It appears that hitting ball multiple times without letting it touch the ground activates the different phases - allowing it to do more damage. I will note that the way it's worded makes it sound like the longer the ball is in the air determines what phase it will be in however.

**My thoughts:**

You can find my first experimentation video [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByNi02RoHJUINE1QdURYN0xfeWc).*  As I said in my comments, I think its a combination of the number of hits on the ball and the time the ball is in the air (the longer it's in the air, the less hits needed to change the balls phase), which would adhere (somewhat) to what was stated on Rocket League's website.

I once counted 7 hits for the ball to lose its shell and reach stage 2.  I also counted 4 hits once for it to enter stage 2. I noticed after 20 hits the ball went to stage three (witnessed this twice - though I think the first time may be cut off from the video). I also reached stage 3 with less hits once (I don't remember how many), which is why I think the air time is also a factor. The ball only ever changed phases after being hit, and if it hit one of the opposing teams tiles, it would reset as it's supposed to.

Around the 2:30 mark in my video, I hit the ball into the air for a decent amount of time after it had just reset. I then hit it once more after it hit the wall and it switched to phase 2. That was only two hits total, but the ball was in the air for a good amount of time before the second hit, hence my reasoning of it being a combination of hits and air time. The same thing happens around the 2:48 mark.

**My thoughts continued:**

I've made a [second video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByNi02RoHJUIbjRnN2pPcmpvekk)* showing my testings, and I still think its a relation between total air time and hits that determines when the ball will change phases. I've also noticed that lighter hits may not be counted. This doesn't mean that heavier hits influence if the ball will change phases,  but that the hit has to be *heavy enough* for it to count.  One thing I was consistently able to do was hit the ball once at full speed and cause it to gain some air time.  My second hit after that would cause the ball to change its phase.

**My Conclusion:**

- The ball will change phases after it is in the air for a certain amount of time and is hit
- You must hit the ball hard enough in order for it to count as a hit to change it's phase

<sub><sub>*Tested in private match with no bots or players on the default settings</sub></sub>

Comment: Currently updating my game to try this out - will report what I find.

Comment: I have seen it take 1 or 2 hits for the ball to lose its shell many, many times.  So what determines if it's 1 or 2 hits?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft through my experimentation, the shell is definitely lost due to how many hits.  I'm not sure how many, as it seemed to be random. As I said in my answer (sort of), I think the amount of time in the air along with how many hits determines it. I recorded a 5 minute capture on my Xbox, though I'm not sure how to bring that video to this post.  I have to wait for the video to be ready on the Xbox App first as well.  I did count 20 hits for the third stage of the ball twice.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I added my video, and my thoughts from my findings

Comment: This appears to still be wrong.  I've seen a ball bounce, immediately be hit and immediately lose its shell.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft but how long was it in the air before it bounced?

Comment: Surely that can't be relevant?  When it bounces (on the floor) is when it "resets" and regains its shell...

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft if the ball is glowing blue, and it touches the blue floor, it does not reset (or do damage - and the same goes for when its red and touches the red teams floor).  Did you consider that as well?

Comment: Yes of course.  I am talking about when the ball resets, immediately gets hit and immediately loses its shell.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I'll have to get back into the arena and experiment more.  I still think it's what I said above. Have you done any personal experimentation as well? Anything else you've observed?

Answer (score -1):

From what I've seen, it depends on how many times the ball is hit without it touching the ground. So, 1-2 hits might keep it at level 1 and hit 1 tile. If its hit around enough, probably 3-7 times or so, it goes to phase 2 and hits 7 tiles. Perhaps 7+ its the third stage and hits 19 tiles. I don't know the exacts, but it might be around those, don't quote me on them, though.

Comment: This isn't correct, numerous times I've seen the ball go full power one hit after it bounced off the floor.

Comment: Your answer is only based on very vague empirical findings without evidence. Try to find sources for your statements!